# NSIS: Despite preproccsor get warning unknown variable/constant "test" detected

Tags: nsis

I use only use some code if the Flag is set. So I got the warning

```
Variable "test" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
```

so I use the preprocessor commands

```
!if ${Flag} == 1
    Var test
!endif
```

But I still get a warning

```
unknown variable/constant "test" detected, ignoring (macro:_==:1)
```

So why do I still get a warning and how could I disable the warning: 
Maybe I could use `!pragma` to disable the warning. But this works only for `nsis3`. What could I do at `nsis2`?

Comment: And what is ${Flag} set to?

Comment: I get the warnings if ``${Flag}`` == 0.

Comment: What does `!error "Flag=${Flag}"` print?

Comment: ``!error: Flag=0``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely messed up your `!if` guards around `$test`.

```
!define Flag 1
!if ${Flag} == 1
    Var test
!endif
```

will print `Variable "test" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!` if you never access `$test` in a `Section`/`Function`.

On the other hand

```
Section
${If} $test == "something"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

will print `unknown variable/constant "test" detected, ignoring (macro:_==:1)` if the code does not do `Var test` first.

And finally

```
Var test

Section
${If} $test == "something"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

will also print `Variable "test" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!` for some reason but the warning goes away if you actually assign something to `$test` somewhere in your code:

```
Var test

Function .onInit
StrCpy $test ""
FunctionEnd

Section
${If} $test == "something"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```